# Use variable (int) as list index

Tags: r

I want to create the following list in R:

```
l <- NULL
l <- list("2" = 2)
```

However, I want to do so using a variable for "2", e.g.:

```
l <- NULL
var <- 2
l <- list(var = 2)
```

This gives me a list, where "var" is the column name. Is there a way to force R to evaluate the variable first before defining the list?

Comment: You mean `setNames(list(var), var)`?

Comment: Or `l <- list(); l[[as.character(var)]] <- var`